# PHPUnit + Symfony: Crawler Follow Redirects Causes SegFault

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I have a simple PHPUnit/Symfony WebTestCase set up to test our site's login form.

```
$form = $crawler->filter("#register")->form();

// set form values

$crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
```

The form will submit to `/register`, and then redirect to `/registered` on success (and 200/OK back to `/register` on failure).

If I use either `$this->client->followRedirects();` before block above, or `$this->client->followRedirect();` after the submit, I get a segfault. There's really no indication of where the segfault is taking place.

**Something else of note**: if I run JUST the tests in this tests parent class (2 tests) i.e. using `--filter [THE CLASS]` it runs fine. If I try to run this test, along with the full suite (~15 tests), I get the segfault.

I've tried giving phpunit more memory using the `-d` flag, but that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be in controller work in conjunction with other component.

I suggest you to use the [Process Isolation in PHPUnit](http://matthewturland.com/2010/08/19/process-isolation-in-phpunit/) so you can run the critical test in a separate PHP process. As Example, you can use the following annotations for:

[Indicates that all tests in a test class should be run in a separate PHP process:](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess)

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // ...
}
```

[Indicates that a test should be run in a separate PHP process:](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess)

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     */
    public function testInSeparateProcess()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: nice one. solved the seg fault for me as well :) thanks for that :)